# PostgreSQL: Column does not exist after table creation

Tags: database, postgresql

I am trying to import a postgresql database through sql code.
I am creating all the tables with their constraints but when reaching the following code:

```
COPY "Customers" (Id, "Name") FROM stdin;
```

psql throws an

> ERROR:  column "id" of relation "Customers" does not exist.

Here is my Customers table

```
CREATE TABLE "Customers" (
"Id" serial NOT NULL,
"Name" varchar(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

ALTER TABLE "Customers" OWNER TO postgres;  

ALTER TABLE ONLY "Customers"
    ADD CONSTRAINT "Customers_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("Id");
```

I've just started working with postgre and im totally lost, any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You must double-quote Id column on `COPY`. Like this: `COPY "Customers" ("Id", "Name") FROM stdin;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive)

Comment: michel.milezzy, thats exactly how i did it initially but i got the following ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: ""
CONTEXT:  COPY Customers, line 1, column Id: ""

so i removed the double quotes

Comment: @StoyanLupov This happens when a empty string is cast to a integer type. Since Id column is `SERIAL` (has auto-increment) you can ommit it from `COPY`.

Answer (score 2):

As commented:

```
COPY "Customers" ("Id", "Name") FROM stdin;
```

Bad idea to create identifiers wrapped in double quotes. Only do it if they are otherwise illegal.